# WinForms open popup usercontrol as menuitem menu dropdown?

Tags: winforms, menu, popup, user-controls, menuitem

Been searching everywhere and can't find a way to do this.

I have a menubar across the top of my winforms program. Now it just pops up a normal menuitem menu. I would like to disable that menu and popup a nice looking usercontrol that looks like its the dropdown for that menu item but includes much more customization. A good example would be the gnome menu bar in OpenSuse or the Start Menu in windows vista.

Can anybody point me to a tutorial or help me out in finding a way to do this?

Right now I know that as long as the menuitem has no subitems a menu won't appear, which is what I want to do, but I would like to simulate that menu with my own usercontrol when that menuitem is clicked.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add my own trackbar to the toolbar recently which involves deriving from [ToolStripControlHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.aspx). I imagine that you will need to do something similar as [MenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.aspx) is a derivation of [ToolStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.aspx).

This is an [MSDN tutorial for using ToolStripControlHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k5etstz.aspx) and here is a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/ToolStripDropDown.aspx) about adding a custom control to a [ToolStripDropDownButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownbutton.aspx).